# Execute C++ program from command prompt

Tags: c++, c++11, command-line, terminal, command-prompt

I created a program in Eclipse and the only way it runs is from a console application like command prompt in Windows or a Unix terminal. I am using a windows OS so I want to know how to execute the program from command prompt, and from a unix terminal too?

Comment: BTW, you can remove the language tags because running a program doesn't depend on the source language(s) the program was developed with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation for the "start" command.

```
C:\>start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
  [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
  [/NODE <NUMA node>] [/AFFINITY <hex affinity mask>] [/WAIT] [/B]
  [command/program] [parameters]

"title"     Title to display in window title bar.
path        Starting directory.
B           Start application without creating a new window. The
            application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
            enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
            the application.
```

Answer (score 1):

On Unix `g++ <file-path>`
Example(from home directory) `g++ ././C++/E1-13.c` To run it `././C++/a.out`
Example(within directory) `g++ E1-13.c`  To run it `./a.out`

Note: you can use other file extensions such as .cc, .cpp, etc.